# changing html "data-to" codebehind (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

Hello i have increasing meter which uses javascript to work.

```
 <section class="featured highlight footer" style="padding-top:50px;">

                    <div class="row center counters" >
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="width:200px;float:left;background-color:lightblue;color:white;border-radius: 15px; border: 5px solid whitesmoke;box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(155,155,155,0.5);margin-right:30px;">
                            <strong data-to="9" >0</strong>
                            <label>New Notification</label>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="width:200px;float:left;background-color:lightblue;color:white;border-radius: 15px; border: 5px solid whitesmoke;box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(155,155,155,0.5);margin-right:30px;">
                            <strong  data-to="6">0</strong>
                            <label>New Message</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="width:200px;float:left;background-color:lightblue;color:white;border-radius: 15px; border: 5px solid whitesmoke;box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(155,155,155,0.5);margin-right:30px;">
                            <strong data-to="5">0</strong>
                            <label>New Invites</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

            </section>
```

for example if i write New Invites' "data-to" = 5 it looks like incresing meter like 1-2-3-4-5 and stops at 5. Can i change this "data-to" at asp.net codebehind? Because i want to assign from database value. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do via inline code:

1) Define specific property in code behind

```
protected int NewInvites { get;set; }
```

2) Use it on page:

```
<strong data-to='<%= NewInvites %>'>0</strong>
```

Another possible option is to use DataBind controls, for example [Form View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf1dk77%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [Object Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try `runat="server"` for the html tag..

```
<strong id="abc" data-to="9" runat="server">0</strong>
```

**Code behind:**

```
abc.InnerText="something";
```